# mudar cor de icone com hover ant design

Tags: javascript, css, react

gostaria de mudar a cor de um ícone quando faço um hover, estou usando ant design

```
<button className="button1">
                <div className="content">
                    <Icon type="plus" style={{fontSize: '64px', color: '#ffff'}}/>
                </div>
</button>
```

não faço ideia de como mudar a cor

Comment: "#Content:hover {
background:#ffEE00;
}" Já tentou isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

Você comentou que está utilizando ant.design e pela sua estrutura parece estar utilizando JSX. Já tentou importar o component de [button do ant](https://ant.design/components/button)? Pode usar ele?

Normalmente a biblioteca já constroi um estilo forte para manter todo seu site com um mesmo aspecto visual, mas caso você queira mudar a cor do hover pode usar css direto aplicando na className com o `:hover{}` ou usar styled-component estilizando o component Button `const ButtonS = styled(Button)`.

O icone gera um i, então você precisa mudar a cor do `:hover i {}`